# How to access the value from the page included without displaying the content in php

Tags: php

Im using two pages first page s getting values from url and its displaying some content. I included first page in second page but the first page should not be displayed but i have to access the values in second page which is used in first page..
The coding for first page

```
first.php
```

In utl the value is passed as first.php?Logid=7773&shiftdate=2013-01-04&shiftid=146&pshift=1&tsid=1&dctype=timebased

```
<?php 
$Logid=$_GET['Logid'];
$ShiftDate=$_GET['shiftdate'];
$ShiftID=$_GET['shiftid'];
$PShift=$_GET['pshift'];
$TsID=$_GET['tsid'];
$DcType=$_GET['dctype'];

// below this some process is carried out


sec.php

<?php
ob_start();
include('first.php');
ob_end_clean();

echo $Logid;
echo $ShiftDate;
echo $ShiftID;
echo $PShift;
echo $TsID;
echo $DcType;
?>
```

The value is not displayed in second page..
Say how i can access the values in second page .
Pls help me
Thank u !!!

Comment: put the values in the session from first.php and access it in sec.php. Or you have to follow the OOPS proramming structure.

Comment: can u give me any sample coding pls

Comment: Why are you using the ob_ functions? That's going to hide any errors that might be occurring in first.php, which could provide helpful clues.

Comment: if the first is right then only v can access second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to access data in PHP "generally" (except in small, insubstantial snippets) is through encapsulation. You could put those values into an object. Then, you will be able to access them on sec.php:

first.php:

```
<?php
class pageData {

  public $Logid;
  public $ShiftDate;
  public $ShiftID;
  public $PShift;
  public $TsID;
  public $DcType;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->Logid = $_GET['Logid'];
    $this->ShiftDate = $_GET['shiftdate'];
    $this->ShiftID = $_GET['shiftid'];
    $this->PShift = $_GET['pshift'];
    $this->TsID = $_GET['tsid'];
    $this->DcType = $_GET['dctype'];
  }
}
$pageData = new pageData();
?>
```

sec.php:

```
<?php
include('first.php');
echo $pageData->Logid;
// ...
echo $pageData->DcType;
?>
```

Comment: Since the properties are all public you can just use e.g. $pageData->Logid = $newLogid

Comment: Exactly. You just treat `$pageData->Logid` exactly the same as you would any variable. Thanks, Matt!

Comment: The idea is that you are creating an object from the class with `$pageData = new pageData();`. Or, in more general terms: `$myObject = new Object();`. Then you can access its "members" and "functions" by using that new name. Such as `$pageData->variable = true;` or `$myObject->send($data);` or `$newData = $pageData->variable`. It's a lot simpler than it looks. This is called Object Oriented Programming and is a fundamental concept. :)

Comment: Oh oops! That should be `public function __construct()` instead. Let me change it!

Comment: Don't forget that you can now treat that object variable (`$object->variable`) like any regular variable in your program. To help you deconstruct what is happening, the first part (`$pageData`) is the object name. The second part (`->`) indicates that you are accessing something from that object. The third part (`Logid`) is the actual variable name.

Comment: hey if i use ur prog as it is .. first page is displaying sec page ... and still i cant access the variables

Comment: A common technique for debugging: Try `echo 'Logid:['.$pageData->Logid.']';` instead of simply `echo $pageData->Logid;` and if your output looks like `Logid:[]` then you know your data is not being passed as a GET request. Another question: Do you have PHP errors turned on?

Comment: ya value is not passing in second page

Comment: So if you change first.php and add: `echo 'Logid:['.$pageData->Logid.']';` (make sure it is in BOTH first.php and sec.php while you are testing!). Does this make a difference?

Comment: What to change in first.php i tried ur coding in my both php.. in sec.php value isnot accessable

Comment: Are both of the files in the same directory? And you are CERTAIN that you are writing EXACTLY the same thing as my answer? `<?php include('first.php');` before you put in the `echo $pageData->Logid;`?

Comment: yes i have used include('first.php'); before ur coding in sec page but still its not working

Comment: And first.php is in the exact same directory as sec.php?

Comment: ya both are in same directory

Comment: Okay, put this: `echo "FOO TEST\n";` immediately after the `include('sec.php');` line. Also, put this: `echo "BAR TEST\n";` immediately after `$pageData = new pageData();` in first.php. Then tell me if you see `BAR TEST` and then `FOO TEST` when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ob_end_clean();` and see that will solve it.

**ob_end_clean** — Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

[**More**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

**sec.php**

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);
   include("first.php");
?>
```

try above code and see if its return any error.

Comment: NO its not working .. The first page is displaying in second page and value is not accessable

Comment: There is no error .. value is not accessable . if i remove ob_end_clean() the page is displaying

Comment: does those GET params passed in URL..?

Comment: ya ya passes in URL for first page

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the values which are set by GET in the page to the second page, am I right? How about trying to use sessions instead.

You can start a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and define values which will be stored as long as the browser is open and the session is still alive. So:

```
first.php

<?php

// Starting the session 
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['Logid'] = $_GET['Logid'];
$_SESSION['ShiftDate'] = $_GET['shiftdate'];
$_SESSION['ShiftID'] = $_GET['shiftid'];
$_SESSION['PShift'] = $_GET['pshift'];
$_SESSION['TsID'] = $_GET['tsid'];
$_SESSION['DcType'] = $_GET['dctype'];

?>


sec.php

<?php

echo $_SESSION['Logid'];
echo $_SESSION['ShiftDate'];
echo $_SESSION['ShiftID'];
echo $_SESSION['PShift'];
echo $_SESSION['TsID'];
echo $_SESSION['DcType'];

?>
```

and use

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

to kill the session and destroy the data in the global variable ($_SESSION). If you want to be extra cautious you can use:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

to make sure everything is really destroyed. A bit of an overkill if you'd ask me but use if necessary.

Hope it helps!